# Maximum Recursion Depth reached Merge Sort

Tags: python, recursion, mergesort

I have been trying to implement merge sort but I keep running into a "Maximum Recursion Depth" error. My current theory is that "if listlen <= 1:" isn't catching it but I can't figure out why

```
def mergesort(listin):
    listlen = len(listin)

    if listlen <= 1:
        return listin

    left = []
    right = []
    i = 0
    while i < listlen:
        if i <= listlen / 2:
            left.append(listin[i])
        else:
            right.append(listin[i])
        i += 1

    left = mergesort(left)
    right = mergesort(right)


    return merge(left, right)

def merge(listlef, listrig):
    result = []

    while len(listlef) != 0 and len(listrig) != 0:
        if listlef[0] <= listrig[0]:
            result.append(listlef[0])
            listlef = listlef[1:]
        else:
            result.append(listrig[0])
            listrig = listrig[1:]

    while len(listlef) != 0:
        result.append(listlef[0])
        listlef = listlef[1:]
    while len(listrig) != 0:
        result.append(listrig[0])
        listrig = listrig[1:]

    return result
```

Comment: maybe not relevant but if you're using python 3, `listlen / 2` returns a float. You have to do `//` (works for all python versions)

Comment: If you have a long enough input, the maximum-recursion error is unavoidable.

Comment: Forgot to add that this happens with as low as 2 numbers

Comment: To split `listin`, just slice it twice.  `k = listlen//2; left = listin[:k]; right = listin[k:]`.  With this, there should be no recursion problem.  This is not directly your problem, but in `merge`, the repeated slicing of the inputs makes it MUCH slower than it should be.

Comment: To better see what your existing code is doing, add `print(left, right)` before and after the recursive `mergesort` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a list of size 2, note that `i` will only be 0 and 1, both of which are less than or equal to 2/1 == 1.

Instead of fiddling with indices, though, just alternate which list you append to:

```
left = []
right = []
for item in listin:
    left.append(item)
    left, right = right, left
```

Comment: I'll pretend I wanted to point out this technique, rather than just overlooking the obvious solution mentioned in the comments.